# Static local variable in Go

Tags: go

Is it possible to define a local variable in Go that can maintain its value from one function call to another? In C, we can do this using the reserved word `static`.

Example in C:

```c
int func() {
    static int x = 0; 
    x++;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Excellent question. I am wondering why this was not implemented in Go. As everything seems to have been carefully selected in Go, there must be a good reason for not having implemented static variables.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use a [closure](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals):

> Function literals are closures: they may refer to variables defined in
>   a surrounding function. Those variables are then shared between the
>   surrounding function and the function literal, and they survive as
>   long as they are accessible.

It doesn't have to be in global scope, just outside the function definition.

```
func main() {

    x := 1

    y := func() {
        fmt.Println("x:", x)
        x++
    }

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        y()
    }
}
```

(Sample on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/onKjdWDtBE))

Comment: say i have a variable at the top of a file? (outside any method) is it accessible to all functions in the file? works on go playground anyway

Comment: Sadly, the function is outside of main, so this pattern doesn't work for me.

Comment: Not sure if we can really compare this usage with static.
Isn't this more like a global variable ... x for func is global variable.

Answer (score 24):

You can do something like this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
  f := do()
  f() // 1
  f() // 2
}

func do() (f func()){
  var i int
  f = func(){
    i++
    fmt.Println(i)
  }
  return
}
```

Link on Playground https://play.golang.org/p/D9mv9_qKmN

Comment: +1 because it is both thread safe (unlike mjibson's answer) AND the function that uses the persisting variable can be independently unit tested (unlike the accepted answer from IamNaN).

Comment: Interesting. My first feeling was that C's static vars are so much simpler, but actually I guess this is much more general and elegant.

Comment: @LostCrotchet I'd be extremely surprised if this is any more thread-safe than a global. Surely, two threads can call `f()` concurrently, and that should cause problems. Two threads could instantiate their *own* functions via `do()`, and then calling them would be thread-safe since they operate on different resources. But that problem can clearly be solved in simpler ways. The problem here is to create a *single* function which always operates on the same set of resources, which surely *can't* be thread-safe by definition. Your point about unit testing is well taken, though.

Comment: Agreed with @AlexanderGuyer this way one can never guarantee tread safety

Answer (score 21):

Declare a var at global scope:

```
var i = 1

func a() {
  println(i)
  i++
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Use Function closure](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/25)

In following example, variable sum behaves like a separate static for each closure a1 and a2.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func adder() func(int) int {
    sum := 0
    return func(x int) int {
        sum += x
        return sum
    }
}

func main() {
    a1,a2 := adder(), adder()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(
            a1(i),
            a2(-1*i),
        )
    }
}
```

Output

```
0 0
1 -1
3 -3
6 -6
10 -10
15 -15
21 -21
28 -28
36 -36
45 -45
```

Answer (score 3):

Like Taric' suggestion, but with staticCounter() returning an int function

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func staticCounter() (f func()(int)){
  var i int
  f = func()(int){
    i++
//  fmt.Println(i)
    return i
  }
  return
}

func main() {
  f := staticCounter()
  g := staticCounter()
  fmt.Println(f())
  fmt.Println(f())
  fmt.Println(f())
  fmt.Println(f())
  fmt.Println(g())
  fmt.Println(g())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In all the other answers, the function containing a static variable is assigned in the main.

Here is how you can define and assign that function in the global scope.

```
var myFunction = func() func(type1, type2) type3 {
    myStaticVariable := []string {"hello", "world"}
    return func(arg1 type1, arg2 type2) type3 {
        // use arg1, arg2 and myStaticVariable here
    }
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// A var x1 is local to main(), is not a global var.
// A static var is one that can't be accesed from others functions just
// like global vars.
// A static var dont disappears when the function ends.
// So is what x1 n x2 are pretending in this program.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

/*
int func() {     // x static inside a function.
    static int x = 0;
    x++;
    return x;
}
*/

// 

func main() {

    //
    var x1 int = 0
    var x2 int = 100
    //

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {           // call to a "static" var x

        x1 = fun1(&x1)
        x2 = fun2(&x2)

        fmt.Printf("%d     %d \n", x1, x2)

    } //

    test1(x1, x2) // a funct needs parameters to see x1 n x2

} //main

//

func fun1(p *int) int {
    //
    *p++ // save value

    return *p //counter  x1
}

//

func fun2(p *int) int {

    *p++      // save value
    return *p //counter x2
}

//

func test1(x1 int, x2 int) {
    fmt.Println("\"x1\" y \"x2\"  ", x1, x2)
}
```