# Performant web-spider with no external dependencies

Tags: performance, go

I'm trying to write my first web-spider in Golang. Its task is to crawl domains (and inspect their html) from the provided database query. The idea is to have no 3rd party dependencies (e.g. msg queue), or as little as possible, yet it has to be performant enough to crawl 5 million domains per day. I have approx 150 million domains I need to check every month.

The very basic version below - it runs in "infinite loop" as theoretically the crawl process would be endless.

```
func crawl(n time.Duration) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())

    for _ = range time.Tick(n * time.Second) {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()

            // do the expensive work here - query db, crawl domain, inspect html
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func main() {
    go crawl(1)

    select{}
}
```

Running this code on 4 CPU cores at the moment means it can perform max 345600 requests during 24 hours ((60 * 60 * 24) * 4) with the given threshold of 1s. At least that's my understanding :-) If my thinking's correct then I will need to come up with solution being 14x faster to meet daily requirements.

I would appreciate your advices in regards to make the crawler faster, but without resolving to complicated stack setup or buying server with more CPU cores.

Comment: If you are receiving a parameter that is already of the type `time.Duration` then you should not need to multiply it by `time.Second`, just call the function by passing `1*time.Millisecond` and you'll have 345600*1000 requests, if you have enough memory to handle it you'll be fine, otherwise just choose a duration between 1 millisecond and 1 second.

Comment: Why do you think that 1 core can only handle 1 req/sec? BTW, `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())` is the default, so there' no need to set that.

Comment: @JimB I do not, my program only uses 1sec intervals to not overload the database. BTW the `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())` is by default since Go **1.5** only and my code still runs on 1.4 version.

Comment: Your bottleneck is going to be your bandwidth rather than CPU power. How many threads your hardware can handle will have to be determined via trial and error. Without a GUI and on a server, I'd expect this to be done with no less than 64 threads/procs. Monitor/measure CPU idle time and network activity to determine what you should use. And as per what @JimB said, remove the timing part, and just poll the db in sets of 100 to 1000 records. Store those results separately (like in a FIFO queue) and keep popping items off it when threads/procs are done.

Comment: @aneroid how do you ensure multiple workers do not process same URL? easier to say than do ;) btw go channels are FIFO.

Comment: Every time you `pop(0)` (first item) from the queue, at some point you'll get an error since your queue will be empty. At that point, query another set of 100-1000 URLs and set a flag that prevents further pop-errors from polling more results from the db. Or if that presents an un-fixable race condition, then let each thread/proc pull 10 URLs (or just 1) from the db which belong only to it. This will require a read lock on the db to prevent race conditions so make sure to fetch all rows before continuing the scraping.

Comment: You can use [go's closures](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30558173/1431750) to make a static variable which manages the poll/don't poll condition. Sorry, don't know much about go but the ideas/methods I've mentioned should be portable. Was thinking of how I'd do it in Python when I answered :-)

Comment: Not really - cannot wait for queue to get empty to add more URLs as this way I can never meet the requirements and process as much as I wish.

Answer (score 2):

Why have the timing component at all?

Just create a channel that you feed URLs to, then spawn N goroutines that loop over that channel and do the work.

then just tweak the value of N until your CPU/memory is capped ~90% utilization (to accommodate fluctuations in site response times)

something like this ([on Play](http://play.golang.org/p/-vDvAenHie)):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "sync"

var numWorkers = 10

func crawler(urls chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for u := range urls {
        fmt.Println(u)
    }
}
func main() {
    ch := make(chan string)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go crawler(ch, &wg)
    }
    ch <- "http://ibm.com"
    ch <- "http://google.com"
    close(ch)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("All Done")
}
```

Comment: This is better approach - thanks! However what would you recommend to ensure same URL isn't processed by multiple workers? Some servers have long response time. I had a simple solution of having additional db column to indicate what state the given URL is in. But it won't work with the above but modified code.

Comment: where I have `ch <- "http://ibm.com"`, you would just loop over the database rows and submit to the channel.   Or do you mean in case you stop/restart your app?